# arm aarch64 assembly: how to compile by gcc

Tags: assembly, arm, arm64

For example, the assembly code from : https://blog.csdn.net/novawl/article/details/5606777

but cannot compile it on OrangePI(allwinner H5 core, aarch64), my usage:

`as convert.s -o convert.o` or `gcc -o convert.o convert.s`

the output is:

```
convert.s: Assembler messages:
convert.s:28: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `@'
convert.s:28: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `,'
convert.s:30: Error: unknown mnemonic `stmdb' -- `stmdb sp!,{r4,r5,r6,r7,r8,r9,r10,r11,r12,lr}'
convert.s:32: Error: operand 1 should be an integer register -- `mov r5,#0@r5=row counter'
convert.s:34: Error: operand 1 should be an integer register -- `ldr r6,[r1],#0x04@load 2-pixel i.e. 4-bytes'
convert.s:35: Error: operand 1 should be an integer register -- `ldr r9,[r1],#0x04@load 2-pixel i.e. 4-bytes'
convert.s:37: Error: operand 1 should be an integer register -- `mov r7,r6,lsr#8'
convert.s:38: Error: operand 1 should be an integer or stack pointer register -- `and r10,r9,#0xFF00FF00'
convert.s:39: Error: operand 1 should be an integer or stack pointer register -- `and r7,r7,#0x00FF00FF'
convert.s:41: Error: operand 1 should be a SIMD vector register -- `orr r7,r10,r7@r7=vvuu'
convert.s:42: Error: operand 1 should be an integer register -- `mov r8,r7,lsr#16@r8=vv'
convert.s:44: Error: operand 1 should be an integer or stack pointer register -- `and r6,r6,#0x00FF00FF'
convert.s:45: Error: operand 1 should be an integer or stack pointer register -- `and r9,r9,#0x00FF00FF'
convert.s:46: Error: operand 1 should be an integer register -- `mov r10,r6,lsr#16@the second byte for y'
convert.s:47: Error: operand 1 should be an integer register -- `mov r11,r9,lsr#16@the four byte for y'
convert.s:49: Error: operand 1 should be an integer or stack pointer register -- `and r6,r6,#0x000000FF@the first byte for y'
convert.s:50: Error: operand 1 should be an integer or stack pointer register -- `and r9,r9,#0xFF@the third byte for y'
.....................
```

it seems the code fully wrong ...

Comment: That's 32-bit ARM code, not AArch64.  You can tell by the use of `r1` and so on register names, not `x1` or `w1`.  Also, AArch64 doesn't have store-multiple (`stmdb`), only load/store pair, making it more of a RISC design.  Anyway, maybe try `arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -c convert.s` or something.

Comment: That can build 32-bit ARM code on aarch64 platform?

Comment: I don't have any ARM systems.  On x86, you can use `gcc -m32` to generate 32-bit code, but I think you need a separate install of gcc for ARM32 vs. AArch64.  So yes, with a cross-compiler or cross-assembler installed (and a cross-linker), you can build 32-bit ARM binaries on whatever platform you want.  I don't think it helps much that your host is AArch64, as opposed to MIPS or x86-64.  But hopefully your distro packages the tools you need to build 32-bit binaries, because I'd expect it's common for people to want to build 32-bit ARM code more than 32-bit MIPS code or w/e, on AArch64.

Comment: gnu is one target at a time so if you want aarch32/arm on an aarch64 platform, which are incompatible instruction sets, so different target. You need a cross compiler/assembler